# Why only one local notification is set?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm adding local notifications with `for` loop, but when I check how many notifications are currently scheduled with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` it shows that only one notification currently scheduled.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = ((int)day - 1) * 6; i < ((int)day - 1) * 6 + 64; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Notification #%d", i);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    NSDictionary *currentPrayTime = [self.prayTimes objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"];

    NSDate *dateToSetNotification = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [currentPrayTime objectForKey:@"date"], [currentPrayTime objectForKey:@"time"]]];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setMinute:-10];
    NSDate *dateBeforePray = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:dateToSetNotification options:0];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.fireDate = dateBeforePray;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%d минут до %@", nil), [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"minutesBefore"], [currentPrayTime objectForKey:@"title"]];

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    localNotif.userInfo = currentPrayTime;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

Thanks for any advance!

**EDIT:**

The only one notification which is showing is the last local notification in the loop.

Comment: Why  localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1 ? badge number should be updated for each notification.

Comment: Please try recheck all dateBeforePray are future date & time.

Comment: I checked, only past prays have old date (<5), others have future date.

Comment: Please consider date & time both . I have tested here its working fine if date & time is future date & time

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck UILocalNotification fireDate , it should not be past date means less than current date & time.

```
localNotif.fireDate = dateBeforePray;
NSLog(@"%@",localNotif.fireDate);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When I check all dates are in future, but only last showing when **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]** called